# Simple button to launch a script in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting started in express and my knowledge is quite limited. I have an entire working script (tested in index.js) and I'd like to launch it on demand when clicking on a button on my webpage.

I want to make sure that my script still goes on if I leave the webpage.

I'm looking for the simplest way to achieve that by updating the index.js file below:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var myscript = require('myscript.js')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to include a button to launch a specific script in my file

Comment: In your view, put a button that makes a xhr call

Comment: I think maybe he means that he wants to start a long-running script in the background on the server so that the client can navigate away and it still finishes as expected.

Comment: @AlexFord, that's exactly it

Comment: @Stephane You'll want to take a look at [child processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You can start a child process, run your script, and get status updates from it.

Answer (score 0):

You talking about building an API.
Basic example you can find at this page (should be enough for your task):
http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html
Just place your script before res.send(..) and optional return result of execution of your custom script via res.send(), e.g. res.send('ok').

To send an API call from the client you can follow this tutorial:
http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html
or use some wrapper depending on your front-end stack.

Comment: I see... if my script lasts an hour, is there a chance of timeout because of the res.send?

Comment: In fact you can set huge timeout for http client, and send response in a hour. But I really don't think that it is what you need. Just send something like 'task started'. And you can find a lot of ways to check when your task will be ended. E.g. check task status from the client with some timeout. And show progress bar, for example. But I don't know what else to say, I don't know your goal.